# Working on my first smart contract for college...Need help with one error!

Tags: addresses, arrays

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ZaPartnere {

address[] partneri = [0x118531D9C6C9114c8B999Ac1197778d1669Fc6c6, 0x029c2D637e193716246A55c62F2302a61FaC81dC, 0x36FFE679f923BdADd17E79Ce159DE80f779b512C, 0x78c426A0ABf24645d7e57267aFEe78688D86937d, 0xF7ffD689BFD99e03b7e1a6ebEc8Ee43877e49EEc];

uint TotalniIznos = 0;
    mapping (address => uint) PovuceniIznos;

    function ZaPartnerePodijela () payable {
        updateTotalniIznos();



    }

    function () payable {
        updateTotalniIznos();



    }

    function updateTotalniIznos() internal {

        TotalniIznos += msg.value;

    }

    modifier ProvjeraPartnera(){

        bool partner = false;

        for(uint i = 0; i < partneri.lenght; i++){

            if (partneri[i] == msg.sender){
                partner = true;

            }
        }

        require(partner);
        _;
    }

    function PovlacenjeSredstva(){

        uint SkupljeniIznos = TotalniIznos/partneri.lenght;
        uint KolicinaPovucena = PovuceniIznos[msg.sender];
        uint kolicina = SkupljeniIznos - KolicinaPovucena;
        PovuceniIznos[msg.sender] = KolicinaPovucena + kolicina;

        if(kolicina > 0 ){

            msg.sender.transfer(kolicina);

        }
    }
}
```

> //got error in remix - Member "lenght" not found or not visible after
>   argument-dependent lookup in address[] storage ref for(uint i = 0; i <
>   partneri.lenght; i++){
>
> ```
>                                  ^-------------^
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You simply spelt `length` incorrectly in your `ProvjeraPartnera` modifier. The loop should be:

```
for(uint i =0; i < partneri.length; i++)
```